# Complete layout programmatically by choosing from different XML files

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, dynamic

I have two activities with almost identical layouts. Only the buttons at the bottom are different.

> *The empty space at the top is an empty `EditText` that is supposed to show the amount of the expense and is filled in at runtime. Same goes for the empty `TextView` for the date.*
>
> [image]

I know it is possible to leave the buttons out of the XML file and fill them in programmatically. But I like the ease of changing an XML file.

Hence my question: Is it possible to choose from two additional XML files at runtime in order to add the buttons?
I imagine that "placeholder views" exist, which can be inflated with a chosen XML layout.

Comment: Add all 3 buttons and set their visibility in activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [ViewStub](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html) would be a good candidate for this scenario. You can specify the XML which should be inflated at runtime, then inflate it.

```
ViewStub vs = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.my_viewstub);
vs.setLayoutResource(R.layout.my_layout);
vs.inflate();
```

Comment: Is there a way to inherit the layout parameters from the `View` that it is replaced with? I have to basically copy the attributes to the `ViewStub` and I don't particularly like that. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create three buttons in the xml file. And Which you don't want to show, you can invisible it.